# Conditional Stylesheets with Firefox/Chrome for CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, conditional-statements, stylesheet

I am doing some tweaks on a website using Stylish extension on Firefox and I want a class not be displayed if they have a link with the word "Demo" in them.

I tried: `.gallery-item > a[href*="demo"], 
.gallery-item > a[href*="Demo"], 
.gallery-item > a[href*="DEMO"] { display: none !important; 
}`

But I did not went far with that at all.

Comment: Do you want to hide "Demo" or "demo" substring? From the [**documentation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) `The case-sensitivity of attribute names and values in selectors depends on the document language`. See [**demo of case sensitivity**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dDuj/) selectors.

Comment: One sec, do you mean the word 'demo' in the class, the href or the anchor text?

Comment: The question edit has introduced an important change. The selector is now looking for elements with `[href*='demo']` that are descendants of an `<a>` tag. Did you mean `.gallery-item > a[href*='demo']` instead?

Comment: Removing the space changes the _combinator_ part of the CSS rule. The main problem was because the _attribute selector_ was still broken. You need to use `DEMO` in the CSS selector to match the markup.

Comment: Ok, well it works in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dDuj/2/) so something else must be wrong. Is the HTML in question the same as your code. Are the `<a>` elements direct children of `.gallery-item`? Are there other rules that have a greater specificity that are being applied to the `<a>`? Check the applied style in Chrome DevTools (for example).

Comment: The example is missing an `</a>` and is therefore invalid HTML. Adding `</a>` and using the CSS in the question **works** for me

Comment: Aww, all right. [Here](http://bit.ly/17NxtEW) is the official link where I try to apply my style. If you have Firebug or anything like that, select one of those boxes or a link with the word demo in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the site is blocked from where I am and I can't do much on mobile Chrome unfortunately. Hopefully someone else can help and if not I can try later when I am less restricted!

Comment: All right, I am looking forward to it. ^^

Comment: Updated my original answer. A CSS solution is not possible with the current markup but I've added an explanation of the current problems and suggested workarounds.

Comment: Note that conditional comments were created to fix the multitude of problems in IE. No other browser has or needs such a facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer, having now seen the [**example site**](https://marketplace.secondlife.com/products/search?search%5Bcategory_id%5D=33&search%5Bkeywords%5D=mesh+demo&search%5Bmaturity_level%5D=G).

**Short version**

It can't be done with CSS with the current HTML. If you can add a class to the *parent* `.gallery-item` elements it can be done with CSS.

**Long version**

The CSS rule

```
.gallery-item > a[href*='DEMO'] {
    display:none;
}
```

does not work with the following HTML pulled from the site:

```
  <div class="column gallery-item " id="product-3779102">
      <a href="/p/BoSH-Mesh-Texture-Changer-DEMO/3779102" class="product-image"><img alt=".:*BoSH*:. Mesh Texture Changer DEMO" src="https://d3qcduphvv2yxi.cloudfront.net/assets/5972439/view_small/T%20changer%20DEMO.jpg?1343233084"></a>
      <a href="/p/BoSH-Mesh-Texture-Changer-DEMO/3779102" class="product-title">.:*BoSH*:. Mesh Texture Changer DEMO</a>

      <div class="item-price">
          <span class="price">L$0</span>
     </div>

     <div class="item-description">
     </div>
</div>
```

because there is a rule with *greater* [**CSS specificity**](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) overriding the `display` property. Namely

```
    .product-listing.gallery .gallery-item a.product-image {
        display: block;
    }
```

Adding `!important` should have worked though, although a better option would be to give the **demo** links a specific class which makes targeting them easier *or* a selector to your rule to give your rule greater specificity. For example an `id` gives a lot more weight to a rule:

```
#main-content a[href*=DEMO] {
    display:none;
}
```

The main problem is that even if you use the CSS directly above to hide the `<a>`, what you really want to do is hide the whole *item*. This is not possible with CSS as it currently has no `parent` selector. You really want to be hiding the parent of an anchor which has case-insensitive "demo" somewhere in the `href`.

In jQuery (which is included on your page) this could be done with:

```
$('.gallery-item').filter(function() {
    if ($(this).find('a[href]').text().toLowerCase().indexOf('demo') !== -1) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

However, even if you manage to hide the items, the gallery is pre-rendered into rows and columns so removing one or more just leaves spaces whereas the items should really reflow to take up the space where some are hidden.

I'd suggest thinking about adding a class to the items with a "demo" so that CSS can be used to hide the items but you will also need to redesign the layout so that the remaining items reflow on the page (if you care about that!)

Hope this helps.

---

**Original answer**

From the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

> The case-sensitivity of attribute names and values in selectors depends on the document language.

The attribute selector is incorrect. You need to use `DEMO` in the CSS selector to match the `DEMO` in the HTML. See the [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/7dDuj/1/) where only the first link will match the CSS rule.

**CSS**

```
.gallery-item > a[href*='DEMO'] { color: red }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="product-4106908" class="column gallery-item ">
    <a class="product-image" href="/p/Mesh-DEMO/4106908">foo</a>
</div>
<div id="product-2" class="column gallery-item ">
    <a class="product-image" href="/p/Mesh-demo/2">foo</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtbXk/1/)):

```
.gallery-item a[href*=demo]{
    display:none;
}
```